# NodeJS Redis Wrong # args for 'get' command

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

Whenever I send Redis using node_redis a get command in my nodejs app, it tells me that it has the wrong number of arguments.  I've tried it with a callback and without and it always says that it's wrong.

```
var user = redClient.get(user);

//and
var user = redClient.get(user, function(err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: That second call should work (in fact, it does for me), although you shouldn't expect `user` to be anything useful, since the call is async and the result of the call will be passed in the `result` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone cares, or I missed something in the documentation, but apparently adding redis.print as a callback to every command fixes this.  Adding your own callback doesn't do anything.